# Automatically Save Data Using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, request

I am working on a website, and want to allow my user to work without having to click save to manually save their data (similar to how Google Docs allow you to work without having to press save). I was able to achieve this by using a on change event in JQuery and using AJAX to post to the server every time that event occurred. The only problem is that this results in MANY requests to the server. How do I achieve the same result, while reducing the number times requests are sent to the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can use websockets which will reduce server load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms you are looking for a “throttle” and “debounce”. There are numerous solutions (e.g., jQuery plugins such as https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-debounce/ – disclaimer: I haven’t used jQuery in years, and therefore have no experience with this plugin), but reading a little bit about it, this is not hard to implement it yourself. In case you use RxJS (not likely in a project that still uses jQuery), there are also methods `debounce` and `throttle` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a timer? For example you could still use the on change event, but instead of transmitting on every change you could start a count-down and only if the user didnt typed for for example 10 seconds you transmit.